# How to make a string resembling an array name with double quote in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, double-quotes, square-bracket

I want to make a string variable -namely

> $myvar

whose value may be something like this:

```
$myvar='somename[5]';
```

and I get the "somename" and "5" from separate varibale:

i.e.

```
$name="somename";
$id=5;
```

and finally I want to make $myvar with an expression using double quote like this:

```
$myvar="$name[$id]";
```

but the result is not what I expect. in fact this expression is read as:

```
$myvar=somename[5];
```

that is null. 
Is there any way to simply get "somename[5]" by using double quote in php?

thank you very much

Comment: `$myVar = "{$name}[$id]";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$myvar= $name."[".$id."]";
```

or

```
$myvar = "{$name}[$id]";
```